# Valid characters for network share

Tags: windows, network-share, unc

What characters are allowed and not allowed in Windows network share names?

For example, are spaces or apostrophes allowed? E.g. `\\srv1\my share\` and `\\srv1\foo'bar\`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the official microsoft documentation, pretty much all is allowed but slashes, angular brackets etc.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file

Answer (score 4):

To add a bit of information, localized char, like é, è, à, etc.., in a share name can get non unicode compliant application to behave badly.

In example QuickBook will throw random error while openning a DB on a share with localized char.

As such I suggest to use non localized share name even if technically you can use them.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently ran across an issue with "#" when in Outlook email and creating hyperlinks to folders. The hyperlinks are on LAN shared folders.  Users can successfully link to a folder with a "#" in the name but not sub-folders of the folder with "#" in the name.

S:\Folder\Sub-Folder\folder\FOLDER 9\ | (GOOD)
S:\Folder\Sub-Folder\folder\FOLDER 9\Folder – 1\Folder\Folder\Folder | (GOOD)
S:\Folder\Sub-Folder\folder\FOLDER 9\Folder - 1\Mary #5\ | (GOOD)
S:\Folder\Sub-Folder\folder\FOLDER 9\Folder - 1\Mary #5\Folder\ | (FAILED)

Same result via UNC.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting! I wonder if the issue arise because Outlook somehow interpret those paths as anchors. (Like in a HTTP URL.) Good catch!